# Como selecionar e pegar valores de todos os checkboxes com a propriedade checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

<sub>Percebi que "como selecionar todos os checkbox com a propriedade `.checked` marcada é uma pergunta bem recorrente no desenvolvimento web, por isso irei postar uma solução aqui, utilizando *Jquery*.</sub>

**Como selecionar e pegar valores de todos os checkboxes com a propriedade checked marcada?**

Comment: Sim, nunca lembro como faz e sempre recorro a Web. Boa pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme no exemplo, vou pegar a propriedade "value" dos checkboxes checados quando clicar no botão e inserir dentro da `<div id="resultado">`  na página.

Considerando os inputs de checkbox:

```js
$('#confirma').click(function() {

  $("input:checked").each(function() {

    $('#resultado').append($(this).attr("value"));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="check1" name="c1">
<label for="c1">Primeiro check</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="check2" name="c2">
<label for="c2">Segundo Check</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="check3" name="c3">
<label for="c3">Terceiro Check</label>

<button id="confirma">Confirma</button>


<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Tentei ser mais simples e objetivo possível. Qualquer sugestão ou melhoramento é bem-vindo :) . Espero que ajude.

Comment: `(this).attr("value")` falta aí um `$`. Também podia ser só `this.value`.

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar o [pseudo-seletor `:checked`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked) que faz parte da especificação da W3C. Nativamente, sem recurso a bibliotecas.

Usando `document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');` obténs uma lista dos elementos que estão marcados.

No teu código poderias usar assim:

```
var confirma = document.getElementById('confirma');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
confirma.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var checkados = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
    resultado.innerHTML = [].map.call(checkados, function(el){
    return el.value;
    }).join(', ');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2mfjkeua/

Se quiseres usar a API do jQuery por exemplo podes fazer assim, usando também o [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) mas do jQuery:

```
$('#confirma').on('click', function() {
    var valores = $('input:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(', ');
    $('#resultado').html(valores);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2mfjkeua/2/

Comment: Opa, obrigado Sergio. Optei por fazer usando o Jquery dessa maneira porque achei que deixaria o código mais simples,objetivo e didático. Obrigado por complementar!